# GKE Ingres and GCE Load balancer : Always get 404

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, gcp-load-balancer

I try to deploy 2 applications (behind 2 separates Deployments objects). I have 1 Service per Deployment, with type `NodePort`.

**application1_service.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: application1-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: application1
  type: NodePort
```

**application2_service.yaml** is the **exact** same (except for `name` and `run`)

I use an Ingress to make the 2 services available,

**ingress.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "my-static-ip"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: "my-certificate"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "my.host.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: application1-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /application2/*
        backend:
          serviceName: application2-service
          servicePort: 80
```

I also create a `ManagedCertificate` object, to be able to handle HTTPS requests.

**managed_certificate.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: my-certificate 
spec:
  domains:
    - my.host.com
```

The weird thing here is that `curl https://my.host.com/` works fine and I can access my service, but when I try `curl https://my.host.com/application2/`, I keep getting `404 Not Found`.

Why is the root working and not the other ?

**Additional info**:
The ManagedCertificate is valid and works fine with `/`.
application1 and application2 are the exact same app and if I swap them in the ingress, the output is the same.

Thanks for your help !

EDIT:

Here is the 404 I get when I try to access application2

[image: 404]

Don't know if it can help but here is also the part of the Ingress access logs showing the 404

[image: LOGS]

Comment: Hi there! Who sends this 404? Do you see the Google page with the robot or do you see like NGINX or Apache error? Is it possile to share an image of the 404? I am asking this because we need to identify where is the error

Comment: Hey ! I just updated the original post with additional info !
Another weird thing to add : both health checks looks to be good and there is no container or service error showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

After searching for days, I ultimately found the reason of the problem.

Everything was fine with the cluster and the configs, my problem was from my Flask API.

All the URLs was like this one:

```py
@app.route("/my_function")
```

So it was working fine on root path with `my.host.com/my_function`, but when I was typing `my.host.com/application1/my_function` it wasn't working...

I just changed my app to

```py
@app.route("/application1/my_function")
```

Everything works fine now :) Hope it will help !

Answer (score 0):

i think you can't use the same port for 2 different applications because this port is used on every node to route to one app.

From docs:

> NodePort: Exposes the Service on each Node's IP at a static port (the NodePort). A ClusterIP Service, to which the NodePort Service routes, is automatically created. You'll be able to contact the NodePort Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting :.

So in your case one app is already using port 80, you could try to use a different one for application 2

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer ! However I'm not sure that the static port (NodePort) you talk about is the same than the port you define in your ingress. In my case the node Port for application1 is 32628 and the one for application2 is 31680, which is indeed unique. Furthermore, if you check this link, you will see they also deploy both service on the same port using only one Ingress : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#optional_serving_multiple_applications_on_a_load_balancer

Answer (score 0):

- I have replicated the problem without a domain and managed a
  Certificate. For me it's working fine using the Load Balancer IP
  address.

  ```
             (ingress-316204)$ curl http://<LB IP address>/v2/
                             Hello, world!
                             Version: 2.0.0
                             Hostname: web2-XXX

             (ingress-316204)$ curl http://<LB IP address>/
                             Hello, world!
                             Version: 1.0.0
                             Hostname: web-XXX
  ```
- Ingress configuration seems to be correct as per [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#optional_serving_multiple_applications_on_a_load_balancer). Check if `curl https://LB IP address/application2/` is working or not, if it's working then there might be some issue with the host name.
- Check if you have updated the host file (**/etc/hosts**) with line **LB IP
  address my.host.com**.
- Check if host, path and backend are configured correctly in Load
  Balancer configuration.
- If still having the problem then check **Port**,**Nodeport** and **Targetport** configured correctly or else share the output of **‘kubectl describe ing my-ingress’** for further investigation.

Comment: Could it be a problem with my app ? It's python running with gunicorn webserver.
Because I also retry the example from GCP, and everything is working fine...
I removed the static ip, the SSL certificate and DNS to be sure it was not coming from one of these, but the output is the same... Root is working but /app2 isn't...

Comment: As per provided screenshot, 404 responses are being sent by the backend. So it might be possible that the issue is with your application configuration.